# I can not write select for get row with min value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have tables `tb1` and `tb2`

tb1

```
id     country   
-----------------
 1     USA
 2     Canada
 3     Australia
```

tb2

```
country    fee  name
-----------------------------
USA         1   USA_NAME
Canada      5   Canada_NAME
Australia   3   Australia_NAME
USA         4   USA_NAME2
Canada      8   Canada_NAME2
Australia   9   Australia_NAME2
```

I need:

by id in tb1 select row. get country in this row. get name and fee from tb2 by country and min(fee).

I tried:

```
SELECT country, MIN(fee) as min_fee 
FROM tb2 
GROUP BY country
```

but I need name too

```
SELECT country, MIN(fee) as min_fee, name 
FROM tb2 
GROUP BY country
```

and it does not work.

I need this if id = 1

```
id          country   fee name
-------------------------------------
1            USA       1   USA_NAME  // min fee for USA
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `MIN()`.

Answer (score 0):

smth like?

```
with a as (
    select DISTINCT 
    tb1.id, tb1.country, MIN(fee) over (partition by tb2.country) min_fee,name,fee
    from tb1
    join tb2 on tb2.country = tb1.country
)
select 
id, country,min_fee,name
from a
where min_fee = fee
;
```

it won't work with several names for same min(fee) though. It's easily doable, but I need you logic for that

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following as well
WITH MinData AS(

```
SELECT  
 a.id, b.country, MIN(b.fee) AS MinFee
FROM  tb1 AS  a INNER   JOIN  tb2 AS b on a.country = b.country
-- place wehere you want to filter
-- WHERE a.id = 1
GROUP BY b.country
)

SELECT
    md.id
    fd.country,
    fd.fee,
    fd.name
FROM tb2 AS fd  INNER JOIN MinData AS md on md.country = fd.country  AND md.MinFee = fd.fee
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can have several names for same min(fee) per country, but anyway you need only one name (not determined which one), then you can also use:

```
select tb1.*, t2.fee, t2.name 
from tb1 
join lateral (select * from tb2 where tb2.country = tb1.country order by fee limit 1) t2
on true
```